# Why are we always to able to find a diverging subsequence of a diverging sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Why are we always to able to find a diverging subsequence of a diverging sequence?

For instance, say $s_n$ does not converge to $s$, i.e. $\exists\epsilon>0, \forall N, \exists n>N$ such that $|s_n-s|\ge\epsilon$. Then we can always obtain a subsequence $s_{n_k}$, which is not the $s_n$ itself, that also diverges, and we can continue the process and obtain a further (monotonic) subsequence that converges.

Answer (score 2):

Saying the sequence itself is divergent means that the sequence itself is a "subsequence" of itself that is divergent.  If you insist on a **proper** subset, removing any finite number of terms from the sequence gives a proper subsequence without changing whether it converges or diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the first term of a diverging sequence, it forms a diverging subsequence!

Comment: But is that still a valid subsequence?

Comment: Why not?
If $\{x_n\}$ is the sequence then
$s_n=x_{n+1}$ forms a valid subsequence!

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a diverging sequence. Without loss of generality we may remove from such sequence every occurence of $0$ and get that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a diverging sequence with non-zero terms. Then by defining $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$ we get that $0$ is a limit point for $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, so by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem there is a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ that is converging to zero, implying that $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ is a diverging subsequence of $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$.

For short, it is enough to map $z$ to $\frac{1}{z}$.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for divergence implies that there are countably infinitely many $s_{n}$ such that $|s_{n}-s| \geq \varepsilon$; let $M := \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid |s_{n}-s| \geq \varepsilon \}$. Then $M$ is countably infinite. Note that $(s_{n})_{n \in M\setminus \{k_{1} \}}$ is a nontrivial subsequence of $(s_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for every $k_{1} \in M$ and that $(s_{n})_{n \in M\setminus \{ k_{1} \}}$ is still divergent. In the same token, the sequence $(s_{n})_{n \in M \setminus \{ k_{1},k_{2} \}}$ is a nontrivial subsequence of $(s_{n})_{n \in M\setminus \{k_{1}\}}$ for all $k_{2} \in M$ such that $k_{2} \neq k_{1}$ and diverges. Due to that $B\setminus A$ is countably infinite for every finite $A \subset B$ if $B$ is countably infinite, the procedure above can be replicated as many times as pleased. This explains what to explain.